# friendly mod_rewrite for search URL with multiple terms

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a way to provide a friendly URL when users search through my site. I currently have a semi-functioning option, however it will only work with one search term. I'd like to be able to have as many search terms added as possible.

I have the URL set up as follows:

http://www.mydomain.com/tutorial/usersearch=word/sort=1

with the following Regex in .htaccess:

```
# Rewrite rule for the tutorial 'page selection' links
RewriteRule ^tutorial/page([0-9]+)$ tutorial.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^tutorial/page([0-9]+)/usersearch=([A-Za-z_%20+-]+)$ tutorial.php?page=$1&usersearch=$2
RewriteRule ^tutorial/page([0-9]+)/usersearch=([A-Za-z_%20+-]+)/sort=([0-9]+)$ tutorial.php?page=$1&usersearch=$2&sort=$3
RewriteRule ^tutorial/usersearch=([A-Za-z_-]+)(/sort=([0-9]+))?$ tutorial.php?usersearch=$1&$2
```

The last line of the above code refers to the friendly search URL I'm trying to create. The /sort=integer part is optional also.
Upon entering a search term and hitting the submit button, the following is added to the unfriendly URL '&submit=Search' so i don't know if this should be taken into account as an option also?

The above .htaccess regex works, but only with one search term.

'http://www.mydomain.com/tutorial/usersearch=word/sort=3' - this works, however as soon as you add a space after 'word' then the URL fails and you get a 404 error. I've tried adding ( )?, (%20)? for optional spaces but it even fails there. I've tried adding a space inside the first character class, but that completely fails.

I'm sure there'd be a way to group all of these rewrites above, but i'm failing miserably. 
Any idea how i can modify my regex so it allows me to match several search terms?

thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect for matching spaces:

```
[A-Za-z_-]
```

Will only match upper/lower case ascii letters underscore and hyphen.

Change your rule like to grab spaces as well:

```
RewriteRule ^tutorial/usersearch=([^/]+)(?:/(sort=[0-9]+))?$ index.php?usersearch=$1&$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I've added that in as the last line of code and it works a treat!
I've no idea which part matches a space in the URL though? would you be able to enlighten me? 
Also, I've adjusted my regex with your example and have managed to compress the 4 lines of code to one with the (?: non capturing groups etc, so thank you! Eg.

`RewriteRule ^tutorial(?:/(page)([0-9]+))?(?:/(usersearch=)([^/]+))?(?:/(sort=[0-9]+))?$ tutorial.php?$1=$2&$3$4&$5 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: My regex: `[^/]+` captures space as well, basically it means match until `/` is matched.